# PHP random string generator more random than expected

Tags: php, string, random, generator

I've been using this to gender a random 12 character string:

```
//  lost-in-code.com/programming/php-code/php-random-string-with-numbers-and-letters
$ch = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@$%^&(){}[]+=-_/?|*#";
$sc = "";    
for ($p = 0; $p < 12; $p++) {
    $sc .= $ch[mt_rand(0,82)];  // 83 is the strlen of characters
}
```

It turns out that it in practice it can include a space in the string. This was not expected!

Why would it be? Does it treat the underscore as a space? It's been causing random (and until now, untraceable) bugs.

Thanks.

Comment: `$ch` is not an array and space is not included in `$ch`. Um...

Comment: @ShivanRaptor `$string[3]` maps to specific characters in a string.

Comment: Just tested the above code. no spaces.

Comment: I run it 10k times. No spaces (` `)!

Comment: @Dunhamzzz prefer to use `substr()` for catching exceptions.

Comment: Hmmm... No spaces is what I expected. But there was certainly a space in a string that *should* have come from here :)

Comment: I think you should show your full code that shows space

Comment: why don't you replace a space after string generation as a extra security?

Comment: See this ideone link http://ideone.com/jvDV6

Comment: That's a good idea, @VenuGopal :)

Comment: So your ideone link shows no spaces, right? There's no chance that one of the non-space characters may subsequently be evaluated incorrectly? What if it is passed by JSON? @shiplu.mokadd.im

Comment: No there is nothing in your string that can be evaluated. If its passed *AS* JSON then you have to show the full code.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. To those that requested the full code, it'd be a nightmare to put it up. As for the space, it turned up in a cookie which was set from the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess (not tested) change the quotes around the $ch string to single quotes. stops the braces from being "evaluated"

---

Edit:

Just to update after some testing - it's NOT converting "as is" - so there's something else in the code that's causing problems. Just ran it over 100,000 times without spaces.

Still put as single quotes to rule that issue out (you may have other variables that are getting evaluated) but that alone is not the issue.

Danger characters are described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: I agree, it could be that $% is being evaluated, either escape that character or use single quotes

Comment: Use single quote for `$ch` to avoid parsing of its contents.

Comment: No it does not evaluate `$%`. I have tested.

Comment: So what are the danger characters in the string, then? It gets passed as JSON, for instance, so I've considered killing braces anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks good. I think that the possible scenario is that you apply some decoding function on the resulting string later in the code. For example "M0i/%20=3ia5" after urldecode will look like "M0i/ =3ia5".

Comment: What if I saved one as a cookie? (I do.) Would that mess it up?  What characters should I avoid using?

Comment: Normally all cookies are urlencoded when sent to browser and urldecoded back in PHP. I don't think that this is an issue.

Comment: Another thought: Do you use setrawcookie()  to set cookie and $_COOKIE array when reading cookies? If yes - you got the bug.

Answer (score 1):

You could end up generating html entities. Imagine if your code generated `&nbsp` or `&#160` for example, a space would appear in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use:

```
    $length = 12;
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
    echo $randomString;
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you tested which is faster?